# Slow load times in QField project

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

We are using QField for discussing results of geoprocessing projects with clients in field. Since several weeks now, we are experiencing absurdly slow/long QField initial load times (> 1h) for our projects.

The strange thing is, that one project will take a few minutes on one device, while taking up to an hour on other (sometimes identical) devices. This was tested on multiple identically configured Samsung Galaxy Tab Active Pro [SM-T545], on Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra [SM-G998B/DS] and a few other devices - all pretty fast and capable.

We also tested this for various projects of different sizes. Our projects are more or less standardized, using similar project structure and layer symbology. The projects load fairly fast on QGIS. The complexity varies mostly in the number and size of the same layers (from small scale 50 MB to fairly big 2500 MB). However we cannot observe a clear correlation between project complexity and occurance of the problem, therefore we weren't able to pinpoint the cause for these long load times.

Are there any known issues with "random"/unexplained long load times in QField?

Are there known solutions to fix long load times in QField?

---

What we have tried so far with no clear effect:

- removing all online-layers (WMS/WMTS) and/or loading in airplane mode (to avoid network timeout issues as is sometimes the case in QGIS)
- reducing project size (extent, number of features) and complexity (number of layers, symbology, themes, ...)
- freeing up space on the respective devices, deleting other projects
- deinstalling QField, reinstalling and updating to the newest version (on all devices)
- make sure no virtual fields are present (we never used those)
- decompressing all TIFs (assumption that decompression may cause load time lags)
- switching back to using .shp instead of .gpkg (we recently converted all files from the (imo) deprecated .shp format to the superior .gpkg format, therefore the assumption that this caused the issue; however the problem occurs with both projects having .shp and/or .gpkg)
- since we have layers that access datasources with identical names from different folders, we usually copy the whole QGIS project structure (e.g. a project.qgz with subfolders \data\source1\my_raster.tif and \data\source2\my_raster.tif); this is a workaround for [this issue](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/2925). To test whether the QGIS projects (.qgz with subfolders) cause the issue, we used the QGIS QField Sync plugin (manually renaming rasters with identical names beforehand); however the resulting QField tailored projects (.qgs with all data in the same folder) appear to have the same problem
- made sure to have no feature count enabled, as this apparently can cause slow load times (according to this [issue](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/3702))
- creating spatial indexes for our files
- crossing two fingers, saying "abracadabra" backwards on full moon...

You may notice, our attempts to find a cause/solution are getting more desperate ;) but we are glad to collect more suggestions and ideas on how to possibly reduce load times for QGIS?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know. When you compare load times on identical devices I assume the devices are configured identically (same background apps running, same amount of free disk space, installed qfield on device and not SD card)? Try posting on the github issues page as well if you haven't already. The devs are pretty nice https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues

Comment: @she_weeds: Yes, the devices are identically configured with QField installed on the built-in storage and have been restarted before to ensure a "clean" RAM. Thanks for pointing out the github issues, I might have a go at that soon; I added two more unsuccessful attempts and as soon as I have some time will try out a systematic strip-down of the project. Offtopic: What is a consulting arborist? (: sounds interesting. Does it combine well with art?